# Android- Rotate image with single finger gesture

Tags: android, rotatetransform

I want to know about How to rotate the bitmap image with single touch gestures.kindly help and suggest some solutions. I done scaling the bitmap with the help of

http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2013/10/drag-and-drop-functionality-to-move.html . Now I need to rotate the whole image while touch and rotate the resize button. How to acheive it?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Rotate means you want to move position of image?

Comment: @InnocentKiller When we touch and rotate the resize button, Image should turn according to the gesture movement.

Answer (score 5):

Check out my blogspot in which i have tried to implement the functionality of stretch the image on arrow click and also delete it, and also you can move the image on the screen using gesture.

[Drag-Drop image](http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2013/10/drag-and-drop-functionality-to-move.html) Also check out the [Demo of DragDropImage](https://github.com/Grishu/MYDroid/blob/master/DragAndDropViewDemo/src/com/demo/draganddropviewdemo/MotionViewsActivity.java)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @grishu. And how to rotate the image while touch     and rotate the  green color icon. How to increase the speed of the stretch functionality.

Answer (score 0):

function that handles rotation with one finger, the main idea is to calculate the centerX and centerY of your view and taking into consideration the status bar height if you using one.

```
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) { 
         switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    rotateX = event.getRawX();
                    rotateY = event.getRawY();

                    centerX = view.getX() + ((View) getParent()).getX() + (float) view.getWidth() / 2;

                    centerY = view.getY() + statusBarHeight + (float) view.getHeight() / 2;

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    newRotateX = event.getRawX();
                    newRotateY = event.getRawY();

                    double angle = Math.atan2(event.getRawY() - centerY, event.getRawX() - centerX) * 180 / Math.PI;

                    view.setRotation((float) angle - 45);

                    rotateX = newRotateX;
                    rotateY = newRotateY;

            }
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```