# Rotate a image with one finger keeping one end fixed

Tags: java, android

I am creating a layout where it is similar to clock ,I need to fix one end to an axis and able to rotate the other end through gesture,
Thank you

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22908379/1777090)

Comment: @MysticMagic Thats pretty long and hard to find for me. Can you please post me selected code for rotate alone.Thanks