# adding sticker to a zoomed imageView

Tags: android, zooming, android-imageview

I developed an app that can add stickers to image with resize, flip and rotate functionality for stickers.
now I want to be able to zoom on image(for example with touchImageView) and add sticker to image and when zooming out image sticker remain in correct postition on image!!
PicsArt android app do it very nice.

how can I handle that? any suggestion?

Comment: the easiest case: use `LayerDrawable` class, if you need more control use a custom `Drawable`

Comment: can you share your code to check it

Comment: which library use ... if you don't use any  library blow link see...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475805/how-to-handle-stickers-with-resize-and-rotate-functionality

Answer (score 0):

Use a Zoomable ImageView:
Implement a zoomable ImageView, such as TouchImageView, which allows users to zoom in and out of the image. This provides the foundation for zoom functionality.

Sticker Positioning:
When a sticker is added, store its position relative to the original image size. For example, store the sticker's coordinates as percentages of the image width and height.