# Manually arrange buttons in layout in Android app

Tags: java, android, button, android-linearlayout

I would like to know how to make a layout like this picture : http://www.noelshack.com/2014-13-1395752335-app.png

I have no idea how I can do that. I already have a LinearLayout with some buttons inside, but I don't know how to move them easily.

Thanks in advance for your help (and sorry for my bad english !)

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, do you want one button to be OVER another one, as in the picture? Doesn't that make for a bad user experience?

Comment: I would like to drag a button and to drop it under or over an other button ... Then the user can sort the buttons like he wants

Comment: I don't think you want "buttons". You want a "ListView" where the cells can be rearranged. Search on that

Comment: Tzoiker has a good suggestion, Android already supports drag and drop, so use that to make your life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You are suggesting interactive moving of items, then You should search for "Drag and Drop". For example: [Drag and drop for linearlayout's child views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834457/drag-and-drop-for-linearlayouts-child-views).

If you want to overlay one view over another - then use RelativeLayout and remember that latest view in xml layout has more Z axis value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_below"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="ButtonBelow" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_above"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_below"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
    android:text="ButtonAbove" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]