# Drag and drop to rearrange elements position inside a LinearLayout? Using android

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

The main menu of my app is a list of elements represented by some button and textviews inside a relativelayout. They are themselves stored into a vertical LinearLayout, scrollable and with just one column.

I would like to know if it was possible with this configuration to rearrange my relativelayouts inside the LinearLayout by draging and droping the elements.

I saw some examples for listview but nothing which can help me...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834457/drag-and-drop-for-linearlayouts-child-views)

Comment: Saddly it doesn't solve the problem, I need my element to be able to take the position of another one, not to increase its margin... as well it makes the scroll bug :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the people in my case, using a linear layout rather than a listview, I recommend this: https://github.com/justasm/DragLinearLayout

Comment: *supports only vertical linear layout T_T

Comment: This library worked by the time the answer was posted, but is currently outdated.

Answer (score 0):

First go to your Build.gradle and implement following

```
implementation ‘com.jmedeisis:draglinearlayout:1.1.0’
```

Then use the following code to to Drag and Drop the elements of the Linear Layout:

```
for(int i=0;i<dragLinearLayout.getChildCount();i++) {
        View view = dragLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        dragLinearLayout.setViewDraggable(view, view);
    }
```